# Figure out the most relevant field of documents when using multi match in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Here's a query (took from here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "brown fox",
      "type":       "best_fields",
      "fields":     [ "subject", "message" ],
      "tie_breaker": 0.3
    }
  }
}
```

According to the elasticsearch documentation, `"best_fields"` finds documents which match any field, but the `_score` will be equal to the `_score` of the best matching field. After executing this query, I'll just get some documents with some scores, but I'll never know what exact field the `_score` was taken from for each document.

How to figure out this without `EXPLAIN`? What field is the best matching, and what is not? I don't want to use `EXPLAIN` because this operation should be constant (to be on a production product), and the backend of my website will use this information to transform the result. `EXPLAIN`, as I understand, is something for debugging purposes only.

My goal is not just to search for documents by several fields, but also get information about best fields which I making a query for. Like, this field was more relevant, the second field is less relevant, but also has some _score. The third one is not relevant at all.

Comment: Why not using different single-field matches with named queries?

Comment: @Val Thank you for your answer. This is something similar to what I need, but I only get matched queries out of it, without information about what exact query brings _score more than others. Or I just don't understand something. In my case, there could be several fields relevant to a user request, but I need to get something like a list of fields ordered by _score (from more relevant to less relevant)